# Yammer - Yammer groups merging

Tags: yammer

Is it possible to merge two groups already existing in Yammer to have a final one ? Indeed, I have two groups for my company and i want to merge them together in order to keep the members and all the contents. Possible ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality out of the box, I'd suggest to use Yammer REST API https://developer.yammer.com/docs/rest-api-rate-limits to:

1. Retrieve all members from the first group

   GET https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messagesin_groupgroup_id
2. Add them to the second

   POST https://developer.yammer.com/docs/group_membershipsjsongroup_idid

For messages, it's not that straightforward - you can retrieve the messages, but not post them on the same date, etc.